# Comparing data between two tables in Oracle with some null values

Tags: sql, oracle, null

I have two tables TableA and TableB, I would like too compare the data of some columns and find differences like name and date columns. I tried with and without **nvl**

**Data Sample**

```
TableA            
id      | name      | date
1       | test a    | 29-01-2019
          

TableB            
id      | name      | date
1       | test abc  | <null>    



select a.id, a.name, a.date from TableA a
            where NOT EXISTS (select 1 from TableB b
            where  a.name = b.name OR a.date != nvl(b.date, to_date('01-01-2299', 'dd-mm-yyyy')))
              AND  a.id IN (select id from TableB)
```

**Result of this query**
No result empty

**Expect result like**

```
id      | name      | date
1       | test a    | 29-01-2019
```

What is wrong with my query?

Comment: Which TableA rows do you want to show exactly? It looks like you are first looking for the same ID in TableB. Is this correct? So, if that ID does not exist in TableB, do you want to show the TableA row? And if that ID exists, you compare name and date and if one or two of the values differ, you want to show the TableA row, yes?

Comment: yes correct, the answer using MINUS is best answer for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.id,a.name,a.date
  from tablea a
minus
select b.id,b.name,b.date
  from tableb b
```

Comment: It is seldom that I upvote code-only answers. But this solution is rather likely to be what they are looking for and the simplest query for the task at that.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want to find rows in `TableA` where there is not a corresponding row in `TableB` where both the `id` matches and one of either: the name matches; the date matches; or the date in `TableB` is `NULL` and the date in `TableA` matches the default.

If that is the case then:

- `AND` has higher precedence than `OR` so `X OR Y AND Z` is the same as `X OR (Y AND Z)` but you want `(X OR Y) AND Z` so you need to use brackets to change the precedence.
- you want `=` to compare the date rather than `!=`
- you want to directly compare the `id`s rather than using `IN` and another sub-query.

```sql
SELECT a.id,
       a.name,
       a."DATE"
FROM   TableA a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   TableB b
         WHERE  (  a.name   = b.name
                OR a."DATE" = COALESCE(b."DATE", DATE '2299-01-01')
                )
         AND    a.id = b.id
       )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TableA (id, name, "DATE") AS
SELECT 1, 'test a', DATE '2019-01-29' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE TableB (id, name, "DATE") AS
SELECT 1, 'test abc', CAST(NULL AS DATE) FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | NAME | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test a | 2019-01-29 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZR13Xc9E)

Comment: Thanks alot for this, the answer using MINUS works fine for me